# How to detect mobileinit and custom events through Javascripts AddEventListener?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, addeventlistener, jquery-events, custom-events

I have an `overrides.js` script, which sets defaults in my application like so:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "fade";
    $('html').addClass('viewGrid');
    console.log("mobileinit detected in overrides");
    $(window).trigger('jqm-ready');
    });
```

The `overrides.js` is pulled in via `requireJS` after `Jquery` has loaded and before `Jquery Mobile` loads. On my page I have this snippet in the footer:

```
console.log("page done loading");
window.addEventListener('jqm-ready', function(){
    console.log("detected jqm-ready")
    // run some code
    });

document.addEventListener('mobilelinit', function(){
    console.log("mobilelinit detected from page");
    // run some code
    });
```

My console displays the following:

```
page done loading
mobileinit detected in overrides
```

So, I'm not able to detect `mobileinit` or my custom `jqm-ready` event through my eventListener added on the page.

As I'm using `requireJS` I cannot use Jquery to detect `mobileinit/jqm-ready`, because the page is parsed before Jquery has loaded. I hoped to be able to detect either event, but no luck so far. I need to detect them because the code I need to run needs to bind to Jquery Mobile events.

**Question:**
Is there something wrong in my snippet or why can't I bind to either mobileinit or jqm-ready like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I got it... I think I can't use Jquery's `trigger` for events that I added listeners to using `addEventListener`. But maybe not. Anyway this works:

```
var trigAnalytics = function( trigger ){ 
    console.log("triggered by "+trigger);
    };
document.addEventListener("jqm_ready",function(){console.log("jqm_ready"); trigAnalytics("jqm_ready");},false);
```

And in `overrides.js`

```
console.log("Hello now");
var evt = document.createEvent("Event");

evt.initEvent("jqm_ready",true,true);
document.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Works.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the event name, see:

```
document.addEventListener('mobilelinit', function(){
                                 ^----- TYPO HERE (should be mobileinit)
```

That is probably why you were not seeing the event.